# Creating CDK after years of building a huge project in management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-devops

I have built a large serverless project in AWS using lambda, api gateway, IAM, dynamodb, s3, etc.

The problem is that I have built everything in the management console. And I now realize that I have to start working in stages (especially since I'm hiring staff to help me code).

The project consists of 95 Lambda functions, lots of IAM policies, linked to APIs etc. Rebuilding the structure using CDK-coding feels like a huge project. Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been in a similar situation where I had setup something from the console and haven't been able to completely rebuild it using CDK.

I think you might like this tool: [former2.com](https://former2.com/#)

fomer2 can scan your aws account and list down the resources created. You can then select what you want and build an output like CloudFormation template or CDK.

From a best practice perspective , I suggest you create a Read only user and use it in former2 for scanning your account.

If you have doubt about former2, you can find it referenced in [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/accelerate-infrastructure-as-code-development-with-open-source-former2/) in 2020.

This tool really helped me many times.

Comment: Seems like a splendid tool. 
Have been playing with it a bit. My problem now is that the TypeScript that it generates the CDK with, is full of TypeScript errors. And im no familiar with TypeScript.

Mainly the issue seems to be that things are referencing themself. Creating a TypeScript error that I don't know how to work around.

 "IAMManagedPolicy4' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own
initializer."

Comment: I created a new question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74316116/typescript-indirect-self-referencing

Comment: I answered it in the other post.