# TypeScript - Indirect self-referencing

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, aws-devops

Im building my first CDK code for AWS and it uses Typescript.

I get the following error:

> "IAMManagedPolicy4' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have
> a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own
> initializer."

The code looks like this:

```
const IAMManagedPolicy4 = new iam.CfnManagedPolicy(this, 'IAMManagedPolicy4', {
        managedPolicyName: IAMRole28.ref,
        path: "/" });


const IAMRole28 = new iam.CfnRole(this, 'IAMRole28', {
        managedPolicyArns: [
            "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
            IAMManagedPolicy4.ref
        ]});
```

This is generated by Former2 that exports CDK code formatted in TypeScript. But i guess the error exists because the two elements refer to one another in a loop. How do I avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have a circular dependency. former2 is great but sometimes might have issues.

I'd suggest to combine the two into a single instantiation.
Something like this should work (I assume this is a role for lambda):

```
const cfnRole = new iam.CfnRole(this, 'cfnRole', {
    assumeRolePolicyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Sid: '',
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Principal: {
              Federated: 'lambda.amazonaws.com',
            },
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole',
          },
        ],
      },
    // the properties below are optional
    description: 'description',
    managedPolicyArns: ['arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'],
    path: '/',
  });
```